# Flutter console log "Failed to send request: {"jsonrpc":"2.0","id":"9354","method":"getVM","params":{}}"

Tags: android-studio, dart, flutter, json-rpc

I have some strange thing happening on my Android studio dart console : every second there is this message :

`Failed to send request: {"jsonrpc":"2.0","id":"9354","method":"getVM","params":{}}`

The "id" count keeps incrementing and i can't find a solution to stop the logs. Does someone have a solution to this problem ?

Thanks in advance !

Comment: Can you post some of the code and give more explanation of what are you trying to do ?

Comment: I have the same problem. Just start Android Studio and click run the flutter counter demo,this happens.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Actually this error is not showing anymore after a reboot of my computer. Couldn't reproduce it but strange log anyway...
Thanks for the answers, if i have the same issue again i will try to find out where it comes from.

Comment: but actually, what does this message means.

Comment: I were also facing this issue `Failed to send request: {"jsonrpc":"2.0","id":"29072","method":"getVM","params":{}}` and after closing all applications and windows restart, the issue gone, it worked for me.

Answer (score 18):

restart android studio  will be enough to fix the problem

Comment: The restart from android studio worked on Mac

Answer (score 5):

This has nothing to do with your app.Sometimes this error appears in the **log box** of android studio....

1.This problem appears after running an app on a emulator/real device.

2.This error always displays after the below message

```
 Enter while loop.
Lost connection to device.
```

No need to worry about this message.

**By re-running your app you can solve this error.**